# WebGL: gl.getExtension('OES_standard_derivatives') doesn' t respond

Tags: webgl

I'm new to webgl and is now trying to do flat shading. I've tried Gouraud shading and it worked fine. So as my first step to implement flat shading, I put
`#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable`
in my fragment shader and

`if (!gl.getExtension('OES_standard_derivatives'))
      throw 'extension not support';`
in my initGL function, with the rest part of the code remaining the same.

However, the canvas didn't show up, neither did the message. By adding some alert messages before and after the above code, I guess the problem is that `gl.getExtension('OES_standard_derivatives'))` didn't respond, so any code after this won't work(including the canvas part).

I've done some searching, but didn't find similar problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what does `gl.getSupportedExtensions()` return. You can just open a console and paste this in `document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl").getSupportedExtensions().join("\n")` Maybe your GPU just doesn't support that extension.

Comment: Yes, it was my GPU problem. Now it's fine. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could include more information about your environment that would help to understand the problem. Specifically these questions:

- What browser are you using?
- What version of WebGL are you using?
- Are you using pure WebGL or a library (e.g. Three.js)?
- Can you post all of your context setup code?

Here is a self contained script that reports to the console whether or not this specific extension is available:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

  function test() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("sandbox");
    gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

    if (!gl)
      console.error("WebGL failed to initialize");
    else
      console.debug("WebGL initialization successful");

    var extension = gl.getExtension("OES_standard_derivatives");

    if (!extension)
      console.error("Extension 'OES_standard_derivatives' was not found");
    else
      console.debug("Extension 'OES_standard_derivatives' was found");
  }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="test();">
  <canvas id="sandbox" width="500" height="500" />
</body>
</html>
```

Save that to a file, open it in the browser you're using, and check the console to see what happened.

Note, in WebGL2 this extension has been promoted to the core profile. From the [WebGL OES_standard_derivatives specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_standard_derivatives/):

> Promoted to core and no longer available as an extension in WebGL API 2.0 specification. Requires GLSL #version 300 es.

Comment: Thank u, I found that it was my GPU not supported. I changed a computer and it works fine now.